# Why does siunitx remove the space after \percent?

Tags: siunitx

When using `siunitx` to write percentages, I run into a problem with missing spaces.
Why does that happen? And what would be the best practice for writing percentages in text?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Siunix will eat the space after \SI{100}\percent as you can see here.
Using 0 \% of siunitx the space is there.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\SI{100}{\percent}` instead

Comment: Nothing to do with `siunitx`: standard TeX concept is that spaces are skipped after control words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use it a `\SI{100}{\percent}` as then things work just fine:

[image]

Using `{}` to delimit parameters is the preferred LaTeX method.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\verb|Siunitx| will eat the space after \SI{100}{\percent} as you can see here.
Using 0 \% of \verb|siunitx| the space is there.

\end{document}
```